# How can I obtain a Treelib representation of the below nested list?

Tags: python, list, tree

I'm trying to convert a nested list into a Treelib representation.

The desired structure of the tree is such that all elements within a list that are not of the type `list` are at the same hierarchy. A sub-list in the nested list is the child of the element (this has to be an element which is not of type `list`) immediately preceding it. For instance,

```
lst = [1,['a','b','c','d',['s','t',['ab','cd',['a','b'],'ef'],'u'],'f']]
```

would translate to the Treelib representation

```
from treelib import Node, Tree

tree = Tree()
tree.create_node(1, "root") # We can assume that the list will contain a root node

tree.create_node('a', 'a', parent='root')
tree.create_node('b', 'b', parent='root')
tree.create_node('c', 'c', parent='root')
tree.create_node('d', 'd', parent='root')
tree.create_node('s', 's', parent='d')
tree.create_node('t', 't', parent='d')
tree.create_node('ab', 'ab', parent='t')
tree.create_node('cd', 'cd', parent='t')
tree.create_node('a', 'a1', parent='cd')
tree.create_node('b', 'b1', parent='cd')
tree.create_node('ef', 'ef', parent='t')
tree.create_node('u', 'u', parent='d')
tree.create_node('f', 'f', parent='root')

tree.show()
```

Desired output:

```
1
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d
│   ├── s
│   ├── t
│   │   ├── ab
│   │   ├── cd
│   │   │   ├── a
│   │   │   └── b
│   │   └── ef
│   └── u
└── f
```

I would guess that this needs some sort of recursive logic to parse the tree and identify the entire hierarchical structure, but I'm not able to come up with the logic for this. How would I write code to generate the Treelib nodes for an arbitrary nested list (which I have manually written here)? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: A complication here is that entire chunks of the tree can repeat. For instance,

`lst = [1,['a','b','c','d',['s','t',['ab','cd',['a','b'],'ef'],'u'],'f','t',['ab','cd',['a','b'],'ef']]]`

should translate to the Treelib representation

```
tree = Tree()
tree.create_node(1, "root") # We can assume that the list will contain a root node

tree.create_node('a', 'a', parent='root')
tree.create_node('b', 'b', parent='root')
tree.create_node('c', 'c', parent='root')
tree.create_node('d', 'd', parent='root')
tree.create_node('s', 's', parent='d')
tree.create_node('t', 't', parent='d')
tree.create_node('ab', 'ab', parent='t')
tree.create_node('cd', 'cd', parent='t')
tree.create_node('a', 'a1', parent='cd')
tree.create_node('b', 'b1', parent='cd')
tree.create_node('ef', 'ef', parent='t')
tree.create_node('u', 'u', parent='d')
tree.create_node('f', 'f', parent='root')
tree.create_node('t', 't1', parent='root')
tree.create_node('ab', 'ab1', parent='t1')
tree.create_node('cd', 'cd1', parent='t1')
tree.create_node('a', 'a2', parent='cd1')
tree.create_node('b', 'b2', parent='cd1')
tree.create_node('ef', 'ef1', parent='t1')


tree.show()
```

Desired output:

```
1
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d
│   ├── s
│   ├── t
│   │   ├── ab
│   │   ├── cd
│   │   │   ├── a
│   │   │   └── b
│   │   └── ef
│   └── u
├── f
└── t
    ├── ab
    ├── cd
    │   ├── a
    │   └── b
    └── ef
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively traverse your list, keeping track of the parent:

```
import treelib, itertools as it, collections as ct
lst = [1,['a','b','c','d',['s','t',['ab','cd',['a','b'],'ef'],'u'],'f']] 
tree = treelib.Tree()
c = ct.defaultdict(lambda :it.count(1))
def build_tree(d, t, p = None):
   last_p = None
   for a, b in it.groupby(d, key=lambda x:not isinstance(x, list)):
      if a:
         for i in b:
            t.create_node(i, (last_p:=(i if (n:=next(c[i])) == 1 else f'{i}{n}')), parent=p)
      else:
         for i in b:
            build_tree(i, t, p = last_p)

build_tree(lst, tree)
tree.show()
```

Output:

```
1
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d
│   ├── s
│   ├── t
│   │   ├── ab
│   │   ├── cd
│   │   │   ├── a
│   │   │   └── b
│   │   └── ef
│   └── u
└── f
```

---

Result on second tree:

```
lst = [1,['a','b','c','d',['s','t',['ab','cd',['a','b'],'ef'],'u'],'f','t',['ab','cd',['a','b'],'ef']]] 
tree = treelib.Tree()
c = ct.defaultdict(lambda :it.count(1))
build_tree(lst, tree)
tree.show()
```

Output:

```
1
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d
│   ├── s
│   ├── t
│   │   ├── ab
│   │   ├── cd
│   │   │   ├── a
│   │   │   └── b
│   │   └── ef
│   └── u
├── f
└── t
    ├── ab
    ├── cd
    │   ├── a
    │   └── b
    └── ef
```

`build_tree` without assignment expression:

```
def build_tree(d, t, p = None):
   last_p = None
   for a, b in it.groupby(d, key=lambda x:not isinstance(x, list)):
      if a:
         for i in b:
            n = next(c[i])
            last_p = i if n == 1 else f'{i}{n}'
            t.create_node(i, last_p, parent=p)
      else:
         for i in b:
            build_tree(i, t, p = last_p)
```

---

Removing repetitive tree components:

```
from itertools import zip_longest as zl
from contextlib import suppress
def tree_eq(tree, t1, t2):
   if not hasattr(t1, 'tag') or not hasattr(t2, 'tag'):
      return False
   if t1 is None or t2 is None:
      return False
   return t1.tag == t2.tag and t1._identifier < t2._identifier and \
   all(tree_eq(tree, *i) for i in zl(tree.children(t1._identifier), tree.children(t2._identifier)))

def prune_tree(d, tree):
   yield d
   for i in tree.children(getattr(d, 'root', d._identifier)):
       yield from prune_tree(i, tree)

tag_d = ct.defaultdict(list)
for i in prune_tree(tree, tree):
   if hasattr(i, 'tag') and tree.children(getattr(i, 'root', i._identifier)):
      tag_d[i.tag].append(i)

for a, *b in tag_d.values():
   for i in b:
      with suppress(treelib.exceptions.NodeIDAbsentError):
         if tree_eq(tree, a, i):
             tree.remove_node(i._identifier)

tree.show()
```

Output:

```
1
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d
│   ├── s
│   ├── t
│   │   ├── ab
│   │   ├── cd
│   │   │   ├── a
│   │   │   └── b
│   │   └── ef
│   └── u
└── f
```

Comment: Thanks -- is it easy to modify the code so that it can be used without the walrus operator?

Comment: @blueberry Yes, please see my recent edit.

Comment: Thanks for that! I added additional detail to the question -- one complication is that entire chunks of the tree can repeat, and the above logic doesn't work in such cases.

Comment: This works -- thanks!I have a follow-up question -- is it easy to modify this logic so that we don't display the sub-branches if they have already been "seen" before in the tree? For instance, the second tree would just stop at the second t, because we "know" what its children are.

Comment: @blueberry I think it depends. In my view, that type of matching should probably occur after the full tree is created via `build_tree`, where it becomes more trivial to simply traverse the tree and search for subtree matches. I will add an example of this in a moment.

Comment: I agree, that makes a lot of sense. An example of that would be great.

Comment: Thanks a lot -- this has been really helpful! Let me have a look.